# Netflow packets and Appication ID mapping

Tags: open-source, filebeat, netflow

i am researching on Netflow / sFlow. And looking for a way to map the netflow packets coming from my Firewall to a Application ID database. Is there a open source application ID engine database available? i am collecting this via Filebeat and sending it to logstash.

cheers
Norbert

sending raw netflow data to a collector and trying to figure out how the flow can give me a clue whether i am using netflix or aws or simply dropbox. i am collecting this via Filebeat and sending it to logstash.